# How can I create a PHP Class named after an existing one

Tags: php, list, class

I'm looking to create a class called a List, seems simple enough right? Not to the trained eye! I'm working in PHP 5.3.1, and due to the fact that there is already a class or keyword called a List, I am incapable of creating a class with this name. Any suggestions/workarounds? Preferably something other than a different naming convention?

Comment: Well, you can use `class_alias("_List", "List");` to make it available it with the desired name. But instantiating will lead to the same token error, so `new $list` would be your next workaround ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[List](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) is a keyword. You cannot use it as a class name. There is no workaround short of hacking apart PHP's source code.

Comment: If you knew that, then why did you ask?

Comment: I didn't ask if it was a keyword. I asked if it could be overriden. Your edit to your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since `List` is a keyword, this is not allowed. Had it "only" been a global class however, you could use a different namespace:

```
<?php

namespace DigJedi;

class ArrayIterator extends \ArrayIterator
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @meagar pointed out, List is a keyword so there's nothing you can do about it in this case.

But since you are using PHP 5.3, you can take advantage of [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) to avoid naming clashes in your code when you want to define functions or classes.